# increase resolution in image.plot map R

Tags: r, image, dictionary, raster, netcdf

I am trying to find a nice way to plot a map in an existing projected grid (137x108 grid points). I found the library fields and as.image-image.plot quite easy and straightforward, but I am not completely satisfied with the resolution of the boxes in display. I tried to change `nrow` and `ncol` but after a critical value (100+) white gaps appear in my map. I am providing an example below, you will need the `netcdf4` library to read the file.

Any advice or alternative approach is welcomed.

```
#Elevation data can be downloaded in the following link,
#http://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.44deg_rot/elev_0.44deg_rot_v9.0.nc.gz

#INSTALLING-LOADING NECESSARY LIBRARIES
install.packages(fields)
install.packages(ncdf)
library(fields)
library(ncdf)

#READING FILES
orog.nc <- open.ncdf("elev_0.44deg_rot_v9.0.nc")
orog <- get.var.ncdf( orog.nc, "elevation")
orog[orog <= -99]=NA
x <- get.var.ncdf( orog.nc, "Actual_longitude")
y <- get.var.ncdf( orog.nc, "Actual_latitude")
xy <- data.frame(lon=c(x),lat=c(y))


set.panel(1,3)
#PLOTING LOW RES
look <- as.image(c(orog), x=xy, na.rm=T)
image.plot(look, col=terrain.colors(100))
world( add=TRUE)

#PLOTING "HIGH RES"
look <- as.image(c(orog), x=xy, na.rm=T, nrow=100, ncol=100)
image.plot(look, col=terrain.colors(100))
world( add=TRUE)

#PLOTING TOO "HIGH RES"
look <- as.image(c(orog), x=xy, na.rm=T, nrow=150, ncol=150)
image.plot(look, col=terrain.colors(100))
world( add=TRUE)
```

## UPDATE

With the constructive comment of tim riffe,
indeed with finer resolution on your data (for example 0.22deg - 272x214) you can set higher number of nrow and ncol in your code, without having problems with the white grid points effect. Still a question remains, how nrow-ncol threshold is defined?

```
#Install Libraries and read data as the previous post,
#but instead download 0.22deg file for fine resolution.
#http://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.22deg_rot/elev_0.22deg_rot_v9.0.nc.gz

set.panel(1,2)

#PLOTING "LOW RES"
look <- as.image(c(orog), x=xy, na.rm=T)
image.plot(look, col=terrain.colors(100))
world( add=TRUE)

#PLOTING "HIGH RES"
look <- as.image(c(orog), x=xy, na.rm=T, nrow=175, ncol=175)
image.plot(look, col=terrain.colors(100))
world( add=TRUE)
```

Comment: add `library(ncdf)` too, for the function `open.ncdf()`, and mention that netcdf must be installed. I reproduced your problem (+1), and found out via `?as.image` that cells with no value to weight from are given `NA`. Looks like you need finer data or to interpolate to get higher res.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, indeed `library(ncdf)` is needed, I modified the post. Also I tested the same example with finer data (0.22deg) and you are right, if I have higher resolution I can plot higher number of nrow-ncol. But I don't understand how the threshold of these numbers is defined, for example the 0.44deg data have 137*108 grid points but when I plot nrow=100+ and ncol=100+ gaps are starting to appear.

Comment: Not familiar with these data, sorry. Guesses: irregular spacing, or else sampling from a different projection might produce such gaps when you superimpose your own grid. Anyway, you can't indefinitely increase the res of the original data. Look at the source, or ask the package author to chime in.